# Apply a function to every element in 2D NumPy Array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to apply a function to every element in 2D numpy array. The following is my code.

```
def fun(arr1, arr2):
  print(arr1)
  print(arr2)
  sum = 0
  for i in range(len(arr1)):
    sum += arr1[i] * arr2[i]
  
  return sum

vfun = np.vectorize(fun)

a1 = np.array([[1, 4, 2], [5, 6, 3], [4, 0, 1]])
a2 = np.array([[1, 5, 5], [2, 5, 3]])

for each in a2:
  result = vfun(each, a1)
  print(result)
```

My expected output:

```
[31, 50, 9]
[28, 49, 11]
```

But I got the following error

```
1
1
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

Here in the first iteration, instead of calling fun(a2[0], a1[0]) it called fun(a2[0][0], a1[0][0]). Why it behaves like this ? Any solution to this ? It is not allowed to change the function 'fun(arr1, arr2)'. i.e, I have to pass two array to function and do the calculations.

Comment: Add a `print(arr1)` to your function to see what `np.vectorize` is passing to.  I'll bet it's a scalar, not a 1d array.  You did read, or even reread, `np.vectorize` after having problems?

Comment: `(a2[:,:,None]*a1.T).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: I have added print(arr1) and print(arr2) in the function and it is giving the updated output

Comment: It is to be done using the given function only (fun). I am not allowed to use other methods

Comment: [fun(a1.T,row) for row in a2]

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj suggested you have to transpose `a1` in order to get the expected output. Do not `vectorize` the function; it won't help. Applying @hpaulj's most elegant code to your situation you get:

```
def fun(arr1, arr2):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        sum += arr1[i] * arr2[i]

    return sum

# vfun = np.vectorize(fun)  # <---- do not vectorize

a1 = np.array([[1, 4, 2], [5, 6, 3], [4, 0, 1]])
a2 = np.array([[1, 5, 5], [2, 5, 3]])

for each in a2:
    result = fun(each, a1.T)  # <---- transpose and use fun()
    print(result)

# [31 50  9]
# [28 49 11]
```